# Программа С/С++ только libc(stl)

Tags: c++, c

Всем привет! Возможно ли что-то написать более-менее серьёзное используя только стандартную библиотеку? Например, можно написать свои SFML функции? (отвечайте только конкретно, если знаете ответ). Спасибо.

Comment: эмм, а как по вашему написаны все другие библиотеки? на каком то другом языке, включая саму библиотеку stl?

Comment: Можно хоть целый браузер написать не используя ни одной библиотеки, правда писать "многовато" придётся))

Comment: То есть, вы хотите сказать, что stl написана на с/с++? Ответа все-же я не получил. (читайте то, что в скобках написано))))

Comment: А по вашему на чём он написан, то? И если вы всё ещё не поняли то ответ да, на C/C++ можно написать что угодно без использования библиотек, любых, включая stl. Может быть для Вас ещё будет новостью что C++ написан на C++?

Comment: Вам придется использовать другие библиотеки, или даже спускаться до API операционной системы, но и то и то вы можете написать самостоятельно. :)

Comment: Написать используя Assembler?

Comment: Не может же вся библиотека написана на С/С++ быть до создания самой библиотеки. Это же парадокс будет. Наверное на assembler написали базувую часть?

Comment: @Danny, так и есть, почти всё, что составляет текущую ОС (средний уровень), написано на Си или С++, включая сами компиляторы, и линковщики, и загрузчики. Ассемблера там не так много (гораздо меньше 1%).

Comment: Я вам более того скажу, что весь научно-технический прогресс построен именно таким образом. Компьютеры делают компьютеры, а раньше транзистор (ОДИН) был больше современного чипа (МИЛЛИАРД транзисторов). Ну и так далее. Представляете, раньше дома без молотка и бензопилы строили...

Comment: @Arenoros А дерганье системных вызовов считается за использование библиотеки или нет? :) Можно, конечно, свою ОС написать...

Comment: @Danny, вообще то может и написана. Даже последнии версии glibc написаны на плюсах. Первый компилятор был написан на С. И я не совсем понимаю что вас удивляет в этом, библиотека и язык вообще разные области, у них даже разные комитеты в стандарте. Возможности языка от библиотек как бы и не зависят.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, таки можно писать и под baremetal)

Comment: Если вы до сих пор сомневаетесь вот имплементация stl от мелкомягких https://github.com/microsoft/STL